# R14 - Memory quota exceeded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, out-of-memory

I have some memory issues for my Heroku hosted application. I am using a worker and only the 1x default dyno. The app is using Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.1.4 with unicorn as web server.

Here is the unicorn config file.

```
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 2)
timeout 30
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end 

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

I am receiving the R14 Memory Issue for no reason apparently. There are no requests to the app, but as you can see from the screenshot the memory used gets doubled in a short period of time.

```
Aug 21 00:47:22 ABC heroku/web.1:  source=web.1 dyno=heroku.27639500.25827f7d-f927-465a-898d-dd87d4376efb sample#load_avg_1m=0.35 
Aug 21 00:47:22 ABC heroku/web.1:  source=web.1 dyno=heroku.27639500.25827f7d-f927-465a-898d-dd87d4376efb sample#memory_total=222.71MB sample#memory_rss=222.70MB sample#memory_cache=0.01MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=62101pages sample#memory_pgpgout=5088pages 
Aug 21 00:47:43 ABC heroku/web.1:  source=web.1 dyno=heroku.27639500.25827f7d-f927-465a-898d-dd87d4376efb sample#load_avg_1m=0.25 
Aug 21 00:47:43 ABC heroku/web.1:  source=web.1 dyno=heroku.27639500.25827f7d-f927-465a-898d-dd87d4376efb sample#memory_total=588.86MB sample#memory_rss=511.95MB sample#memory_cache=0.01MB sample#memory_swap=76.91MB sample#memory_pgpgin=156028pages sample#memory_pgpgout=24968pages 
Aug 21 00:47:43 ABC heroku/web.1:  Process running mem=588M(115.0%) 
Aug 21 00:47:43 ABC heroku/web.1:  Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) 
Aug 21 00:48:04 ABC heroku/web.1:  source=web.1 dyno=heroku.27639500.25827f7d-f927-465a-898d-dd87d4376efb sample#load_avg_1m=0.17 
Aug 21 00:48:04 ABC heroku/web.1:  source=web.1 dyno=heroku.27639500.25827f7d-f927-465a-898d-dd87d4376efb sample#memory_total=177.77MB sample#memory_rss=83.40MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=94.36MB sample#memory_pgpgin=181821pages sample#memory_pgpgout=160469pages
```

Thanks!

Comment: Screenshots aren't very useful when too tiny, and where pasting in the plain (and searchable) text would do the job.

Comment: In general, in heroku one dyno having 512MB of memory. So in that case if a dyno requires memory in excess of its quota (512 MB on 1X dynos) then heroku rises R14 error. If this error occurs, the dyno will page to swap space to continue running, which may cause degraded process performance. check here once https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/troubleshooting

I am experiencing the same problem with rails4, I felt it is a bug.

Comment: What is the value of ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] ?

Comment: In the heroku config env variables there is no WEB_CONCURRENCY. :)

Comment: Check your app for big constants. Look for any class instance variables (or class variables) that could be very large.

Comment: This gem can help you track down memory issues: https://github.com/noahd1/oink

Comment: @LukasEklund WEB_CONCURRENCY is for unicorn's config, we often add it into heroku variables manually

Comment: Paste your gem list. This could also help a little bit. Maybe use NewRelic, to check what request are performed before R14.

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing the Ruby Garbage Collection can help a lot with keeping used memory low on a heroku instance. If Ruby triggers GC more frequently, this has the slight downside of burning some CPU cycles, but will keep memory usage down.

Especially high (default) values of `RUBY_GC_HEAP_GROWTH_FACTOR` can cause `Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)`.

Its default value is `1.8`, meaning that if the heap size needs to be expanded it will grow by 80%. You could try lowering this value to anything between `1.1`and `1.5`.